# How to convert video file saving all metadata except global?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have .m4a video file.

mediainfo:

```
General
Complete name                            : C:\foo\Brazil (HD).m4v
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Codec ID                                 : M4V 
File size                                : 5.41 GiB
Duration                                 : 2h 23mn
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 5 403 Kbps
Movie name                               : Бразилия
Performer                                : Терри Гиллиам
Genre                                    : Drama & Fantasy & Sci-Fi
Recorded date                            : UTC 1985-12-18 07:00:00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-10-25 14:23:32
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-10-25 15:02:19
Copyright                                : © Universal Studios Home Entertainmen
Cover                                    : Yes
Comment                                  : «Suspicion breeds confidence.»
sonm                                     : Brazil
desc                                     : Сэм Лоури — крошечный винтик в огромной заржавевшей бюрократической машине тоталитарного государства будущего. Сэм старается не лезть в неприятности, но однажды, заметив ошибку в документе, которая привела к аресту невинного человека, он решает испра
ldes                                     : Сэм Лоури — крошечный винтик в огромной заржавевшей бюрократической машине тоталитарного государства будущего. Сэм старается не лезть в неприятности, но однажды, заметив ошибку в документе, которая привела к аресту невинного человека, он решает исправить ее. Благое намерение скромного клерка неожиданно для него вызывает целую лавину странных совпадений и загадочных событий, и вскоре выясняется, что крошечная опечатка способна пошатнуть могучего колосса на глиняных ногах.
hdvd                                     : 1
stik                                     : 9
rtng                                     : 0
akID                                     : -1
sfID                                     : 0
cnID                                     : 483
xid                                      : Apple:vendor_id:1985-483
iTunEXTC                                 : mpaa|R|400|
iTunMOVI                                 : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> / <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> / <plist version="1.0"> / <dict> /   <key>cast</key> /   <array> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Джонатан Прайс</string> /       </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Роберт Де Ниро</string> /       </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Кэтрин Хелмонд</string> /       </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Иэн Холм</string> /         </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Боб Хоскинс</string> /      </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Майкл Пэлин</string> /      </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Иэн Ричардсон</string> /        </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Питер Вон</string> /        </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Ким Грайст</string> /       </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Джим Броудбент</string> /       </dict> /   </array> /  <key>directors</key> /  <array> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Терри Гиллиам</string> /        </dict> /   </array> /  <key>producers</key> /  <array> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Патрик Кассаветти</string> /        </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Арнон Милчэн</string> /         </dict> /   </array> /  <key>screenwriters</key> /  <array> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Терри Гиллиам</string> /        </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Том Стоппард</string> /         </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Чарльз МакКоуэн</string> /      </dict> /   </array> /  <key>studio</key> /     <string>Universal Studios Home Entertainmen</string> / </dict> / </plist>

Video #1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC                   : No
Format settings, ReFrames                : 3 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 2h 23mn
Bit rate                                 : 5 000 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 11.9 Mbps
Width                                    : 1 280 pixels
Height                                   : 688 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.85:1
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 23.976 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.237
Stream size                              : 5.01 GiB (93%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 128 r2216 198a7ea
Encoding settings                        : cabac=0 / ref=3 / deblock=1:-1:-1 / analyse=0x3:0x133 / me=umh / subme=9 / psy=1 / psy_rd=0.70:0.20 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=32 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=2 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=0 / chroma_qp_offset=-3 / threads=18 / lookahead_threads=3 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=0 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=0 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=3 / weightb=0 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=250 / keyint_min=23 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=60 / rc=2pass / mbtree=0 / bitrate=5000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.65 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / vbv_maxrate=9500 / vbv_bufsize=9500 / nal_hrd=none / ip_ratio=1.40 / pb_ratio=1.20 / aq=2:0.90
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-10-25 14:23:32
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-10-25 14:25:18
Matrix coefficients                      : BT.709

Video #2
ID                                       : 7
Format                                   : JPEG
Codec ID                                 : jpeg
Duration                                 : 2h 23mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 1 174 bps
Width                                    : 640 pixels
Height                                   : 344 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.85:1
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 0.003 fps
Minimum frame rate                       : 0.002 fps
Maximum frame rate                       : 0.050 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 1.777
Stream size                              : 1.31 MiB (0%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:48
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:49

Audio #1
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 2h 23mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 198 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 312 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 203 MiB (4%)
Language                                 : Russian
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-10-25 14:38:16
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-10-25 14:38:19

Audio #2
ID                                       : 3
Format                                   : AAC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                           : LC
Codec ID                                 : 40
Duration                                 : 2h 23mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 198 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                         : 303 Kbps
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel positions                        : Front: L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 204 MiB (4%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:30
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:35

Text #1
ID                                       : 4
Format                                   : Timed text
Muxing mode                              : sbtl
Codec ID                                 : tx3g
Duration                                 : 2h 23mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 58 bps
Stream size                              : 60.9 KiB (0%)
Language                                 : Russian
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:30
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:35

Text #2
ID                                       : 5
Format                                   : Timed text
Muxing mode                              : sbtl
Codec ID                                 : tx3g
Duration                                 : 2h 23mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 43 bps
Stream size                              : 45.3 KiB (0%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:30
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:35

Text #3
ID                                       : 6
Format                                   : Apple text
Codec ID                                 : text
Duration                                 : 2h 23mn
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 1 bps
Stream size                              : 663 Bytes (0%)
Language                                 : English
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:35
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-10-25 14:51:35

Menu
00:00:00.000                             : Chapter 1
00:01:54.072                             : Chapter 2
00:07:29.658                             : Chapter 3
00:12:29.415                             : Chapter 4
00:15:46.237                             : Chapter 5
00:23:53.015                             : Chapter 6
00:34:30.944                             : Chapter 7
00:39:55.768                             : Chapter 8
00:44:57.361                             : Chapter 9
00:51:23.247                             : Chapter 10
00:57:26.777                             : Chapter 11
00:58:59.995                             : Chapter 12
01:05:53.241                             : Chapter 13
01:11:07.597                             : Chapter 14
01:15:30.693                             : Chapter 15
01:21:53.742                             : Chapter 16
01:31:27.440                             : Chapter 17
01:31:47.419                             : Chapter 18
01:37:36.059                             : Chapter 19
01:43:13.646                             : Chapter 20
01:47:04.293                             : Chapter 21
01:51:01.613                             : Chapter 22
01:53:23.088                             : Chapter 23
02:00:08.827                             : Chapter 24
02:05:13.005                             : Chapter 25
02:08:00.965                             : Chapter 26
02:13:51.106                             : Chapter 27
02:19:18.475                             : Chapter 28
```

ffmpeg log:

```
C:\foo>ffmpeg -i "Brazil (HD).m4v"
ffmpeg version N-57906-gbd75651 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Nov  4 2013 18:09:19 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3
 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --ena
ble-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --e
nable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-lib
modplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrw
b --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinge
r --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --en
able-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis
 --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-
libxvid --enable-zlib
  libavutil      52. 51.100 / 52. 51.100
  libavcodec     55. 41.100 / 55. 41.100
  libavformat    55. 21.100 / 55. 21.100
  libavdevice    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavfilter     3. 90.101 /  3. 90.101
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000000007d9320] stream 0, timescale not set
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Brazil (HD).m4v':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : M4V
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1M4V mp42
    creation_time   : 2012-10-25 14:23:32
    title           : ╨С╤А╨░╨╖╨╕╨╗╨╕╤П
    artist          : ╨в╨╡╤А╤А╨╕ ╨У╨╕╨╗╨╗╨╕╨░╨╝
    comment         : ┬лSuspicion breeds confidence.┬╗
    genre           : Drama & Fantasy & Sci-Fi
    date            : 1985-12-18T07:00:00Z
    description     : ╨б╤Н╨╝ ╨Ы╨╛╤Г╤А╨╕ тАФ ╨║╤А╨╛╤И╨╡╤З╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨▓╨╕╨╜╤В╨╕╨║ ╨▓ ╨
╛╨│╤А╨╛╨╝╨╜╨╛╨╣ ╨╖╨░╤А╨╢╨░╨▓╨╡╨▓╤И╨╡╨╣ ╨▒╤О╤А╨╛╨║╤А╨░╤В╨╕╤З╨╡╤Б╨║╨╛╨╣ ╨╝╨░╤И╨╕╨╜
╨╡ ╤В╨╛╤В╨░╨╗╨╕╤В╨░╤А╨╜╨╛╨│╨╛ ╨│╨╛╤Б╤Г╨┤╨░╤А╤Б╤В╨▓╨░ ╨▒╤Г╨┤╤Г╤Й╨╡╨│╨╛. ╨б╤Н╨╝ ╤Б
╤В╨░╤А╨░╨╡╤В╤Б╤П ╨╜╨╡ ╨╗╨╡╨╖╤В╤М ╨▓ ╨
    synopsis        : ╨б╤Н╨╝ ╨Ы╨╛╤Г╤А╨╕ тАФ ╨║╤А╨╛╤И╨╡╤З╨╜╤Л╨╣ ╨▓╨╕╨╜╤В╨╕╨║ ╨▓ ╨
╛╨│╤А╨╛╨╝╨╜╨╛╨╣ ╨╖╨░╤А╨╢╨░╨▓╨╡╨▓╤И╨╡╨╣ ╨▒╤О╤А╨╛╨║╤А╨░╤В╨╕╤З╨╡╤Б╨║╨╛╨╣ ╨╝╨░╤И╨╕╨╜
╨╡ ╤В╨╛╤В╨░╨╗╨╕╤В╨░╤А╨╜╨╛╨│╨╛ ╨│╨╛╤Б╤Г╨┤╨░╤А╤Б╤В╨▓╨░ ╨▒╤Г╨┤╤Г╤Й╨╡╨│╨╛. ╨б╤Н╨╝ ╤Б
╤В╨░╤А╨░╨╡╤В╤Б╤П ╨╜╨╡ ╨╗╨╡╨╖╤В╤М ╨▓ ╨
    copyright       : ┬й Universal Studios Home Entertainmen
    hd_video        : 1
    media_type      : 9
  Duration: 02:23:20.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5403 kb/s
    Chapter #0.0: start 0.000000, end 114.072000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0.1: start 114.072000, end 449.658000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0.2: start 449.658000, end 749.415000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0.3: start 749.415000, end 946.237000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0.4: start 946.237000, end 1433.015000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0.5: start 1433.015000, end 2070.944000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0.6: start 2070.944000, end 2395.768000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0.7: start 2395.768000, end 2697.361000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0.8: start 2697.361000, end 3083.247000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0.9: start 3083.247000, end 3446.777000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0.10: start 3446.777000, end 3539.995000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0.11: start 3539.995000, end 3953.241000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0.12: start 3953.241000, end 4267.597000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0.13: start 4267.597000, end 4530.693000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0.14: start 4530.693000, end 4913.742000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0.15: start 4913.742000, end 5487.440000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Chapter #0.16: start 5487.440000, end 5507.419000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 17
    Chapter #0.17: start 5507.419000, end 5856.059000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 18
    Chapter #0.18: start 5856.059000, end 6193.646000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 19
    Chapter #0.19: start 6193.646000, end 6424.293000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 20
    Chapter #0.20: start 6424.293000, end 6661.613000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 21
    Chapter #0.21: start 6661.613000, end 6803.088000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 22
    Chapter #0.22: start 6803.088000, end 7208.827000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 23
    Chapter #0.23: start 7208.827000, end 7513.005000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 24
    Chapter #0.24: start 7513.005000, end 7680.965000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 25
    Chapter #0.25: start 7680.965000, end 8031.106000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 26
    Chapter #0.26: start 8031.106000, end 8358.475000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 27
    Chapter #0.27: start 8358.475000, end 8600.633000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 28
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709)
, 1280x688, 4999 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-25 14:23:32
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 1000x1500 [SAR 300:300 DAR 2:3], 90
k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0:2(rus): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 19
7 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-25 14:38:16
    Stream #0:3(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 19
8 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-25 14:51:30
    Stream #0:4(rus): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 1280x103, 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-25 14:51:30
    Stream #0:5(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (tx3g / 0x67337874), 1280x103, 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-25 14:51:30
    Stream #0:6(eng): Subtitle: mov_text (text / 0x74786574)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-25 14:51:35
    Stream #0:7(eng): Video: mjpeg (jpeg / 0x6765706A), yuvj420p(pc), 640x344 [S
AR 1:1 DAR 80:43], 1 kb/s, 0k fps, 1k tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-10-25 14:51:48
At least one output file must be specified
```

Want to convert to mkv and omit:

```
Movie name                               : Бразилия
Performer                                : Терри Гиллиам
Genre                                    : Drama & Fantasy & Sci-Fi
Recorded date                            : UTC 1985-12-18 07:00:00
Encoded date                             : UTC 2012-10-25 14:23:32
Tagged date                              : UTC 2012-10-25 15:02:19
Copyright                                : © Universal Studios Home Entertainmen
Cover                                    : Yes
Comment                                  : «Suspicion breeds confidence.»
sonm                                     : Brazil
desc                                     : Сэм Лоури — крошечный винтик в огромной заржавевшей бюрократической машине тоталитарного государства будущего. Сэм старается не лезть в неприятности, но однажды, заметив ошибку в документе, которая привела к аресту невинного человека, он решает испра
ldes                                     : Сэм Лоури — крошечный винтик в огромной заржавевшей бюрократической машине тоталитарного государства будущего. Сэм старается не лезть в неприятности, но однажды, заметив ошибку в документе, которая привела к аресту невинного человека, он решает исправить ее. Благое намерение скромного клерка неожиданно для него вызывает целую лавину странных совпадений и загадочных событий, и вскоре выясняется, что крошечная опечатка способна пошатнуть могучего колосса на глиняных ногах.
hdvd                                     : 1
stik                                     : 9
rtng                                     : 0
akID                                     : -1
sfID                                     : 0
cnID                                     : 483
xid                                      : Apple:vendor_id:1985-483
iTunEXTC                                 : mpaa|R|400|
iTunMOVI                                 : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> / <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> / <plist version="1.0"> / <dict> /   <key>cast</key> /   <array> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Джонатан Прайс</string> /       </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Роберт Де Ниро</string> /       </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Кэтрин Хелмонд</string> /       </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Иэн Холм</string> /         </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Боб Хоскинс</string> /      </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Майкл Пэлин</string> /      </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Иэн Ричардсон</string> /        </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Питер Вон</string> /        </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Ким Грайст</string> /       </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Джим Броудбент</string> /       </dict> /   </array> /  <key>directors</key> /  <array> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Терри Гиллиам</string> /        </dict> /   </array> /  <key>producers</key> /  <array> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Патрик Кассаветти</string> /        </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Арнон Милчэн</string> /         </dict> /   </array> /  <key>screenwriters</key> /  <array> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Терри Гиллиам</string> /        </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Том Стоппард</string> /         </dict> /       <dict> /            <key>name</key> /           <string>Чарльз МакКоуэн</string> /      </dict> /   </array> /  <key>studio</key> /     <string>Universal Studios Home Entertainmen</string> / </dict> / </plist>
```

use this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "Brazil (HD).m4v" -map 0 -map -0:v:1 -map -0:v:2 -map -0:s:2 -map_chapters 0 -map_metadata -0:g -c copy -c:s ass "Brazil (HD).mkv"
```

And it still copies all the metadata. So, i have to set `-map_metadata` options to copy all per-stream metadata but omit global one. How to do this?

Comment: Please provide a short input file.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Ok. ffmpeg couldn't just cut m4v, so [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74488477/sample.mkv) i converted it to mkv and [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74488477/sample2.m4v) i cut the file with dd